# Sencha Touch 2 - App permissions & App icon

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I edited the packager.json file to edit app permissions from:

```
"permissions":[
        "INTERNET"
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "CAMERA",
        "VIBRATE",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "CALL_PHONE"
    ]
```

To:

```
"permissions":[
        "INTERNET"
    ]
```

But when I install the app it says that is using all permisions instead of  internet permission only.

And how can I change the app icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics).Adding or creating the config.xml file in the index.html path with the distinc configs.